# PHP: Facebook Event API start_time doesn't show today's events

Tags: php, sql, facebook, date, facebook-fql

I'm fetching Facebook events to my site but have problem that today's events disappear one day to early. If there is an event today it will not show on my site, today. At 00:00 today the event disappears from the view.

**I use the code below:**

```
<?php

//we have to set timezone to California
date_default_timezone_set('California');

//requiring FB PHP SDK
require 'fb-sdk/src/facebook.php';

//initializing keys
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => 'APP_ID',
        'secret' => 'APP_SECRET',
        'cookie' => true, // enable optional cookie support
));

$fql    =   "SELECT eid, name, pic, start_time, end_time, location, description, attending_count FROM event WHERE eid IN ( SELECT eid FROM 
event_member WHERE uid = PAGE_ID) AND start_time >= now() ORDER BY start_time ASC";
$param  =   array(
'method'    => 'fql.query',
'query'     => $fql,
'callback'  => ''
);

$fqlResult   =   $facebook->api($param);

//looping through retrieved data
foreach( $fqlResult as $keys => $values ) {

        $start_date = date( 'l, F d, Y', $values['start_time'] );
        $end_date = date( 'l, F d, Y', $values['end_time'] );

        $start_time = date( 'g:i a', $values['start_time'] );
        $end_time = date( 'g:i a', $values['end_time'] );

        $time = explode("T", $values['start_time']);
        $tid = explode("+", $time[1]);

        if ($time[0] > date("Y-m-d"))
        {

                //printing the data
                echo "<div class='event'>";
                echo "<div>";

                        echo "<table><tr><td valign='top'>";
                        echo "<img src={$values['pic']} width='100px' />";
                        echo "</td><td valign='top'>";

                        echo "<span style='font-family:verdana;font-size:10pt;'><b>" . $values['name'] . "</b></span><br>";
                        echo "<span style='font-family:verdana;font-size:9pt; color:#666666; line-height:7pt;'>".$time[0]." kl ".substr($tid[0],0,5)."<br>";
                        echo "Place: " . $values['location'] . "<br>".$values['attending_count']. " attendings.<br>";
                        echo "<a href='https://www.facebook.com/events/".$values['eid']."/' target='_blank'><br>More info</a></span>";

                        echo "</td></tr></table><br>";

                echo "</div>";
                echo "</div>";
        }

}

?>
```

`date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');` doesn't work.

Does anyone knows why?
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE -> SOLUTION**

Change `if ($time[0] > date("Y-m-d"))` to `if ($time[0] >= date("Y-m-d"))` and it will display events from today.

Answer (score 0):

If you use FQL function `now()`, you won't get events, that have started today and are before current time. Instead use your own variable `$now` instead of function `now()`:

```php
$now = strtotime('today');
$fql = "SELECT ... WHERE ... start_date >= $now ...";
```

---

Returned timestamps (`start_date` and `end_date`) are in UTC timezone, so if you wish to format in your timezone:

```php
$start = new DateTime('@'.$values['start_time']);
$start->setTimezone(new DateTimezone('America/Los_Angeles'));
$start->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

---

You should also take a look at this link: [Platform Migration: Events Timezone Support](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/08/01/platform-migration--events-timezone-support/)

Comment: Updated the question with the solution. :)